# dropbox cannot undo event to restore files

Tags: dropbox, restore, undelete

I accidentally deleted fifty thousand files from dropbox. The event still exists in my dropbox, so I tried to restore these files, as shown in the picture below. However, after clicking "Restore these files", it shows a message "Too many files please use the desktop application"

Do you have any suggestions? Please help me out, thank you!

[image]

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask Dropbox support for help with: https://www.dropbox.com/support

Comment: I have asked dropbox support and here is their reply



Dropbox Support, Feb 8, 12:10 AM:
Hi,
Thanks for writing in. While we'd love to answer every question we get, we unfortunately can't respond to your inquiry due to a large volume of support requests. Here are some resources for resolving the most common issues:

Restore files or folders - www.dropbox.com/help/969
Learn about Dropbox's desktop app - www.dropbox.com/help/category/Desktop

For all other issues, please check out our Help Center - www.dropbox.com/help
We're sorry for the inconvenience,
The Dropbox Team

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the same issue and here is what I did (which worked):

1. It seems that "desktop" message is just a generic one. I tried
   working thru the desktop but found no option.
2. Went back to the Dropbox home page on the web. It has a trash can icon which one can toggle to either show/hide deleted folders.  I did "show deleted  folders". Then on clicking deleted folders, I was able to get to   "restore folder" option.
3. However, that did not work and I got the message that there were too many files in the folder, contact  support Luckily, my folders had multiple sub folder under it. I was then able to go to each sub-folder and restore. The largest sub-folder that i was able to restore in one click had about 25K files.
   By the end of the process (sub folder by sub-folder), I was able to restore all 50K files.

Note: You may have to do this within 30 days of deletion to recover (unless you have a pro or business accounts)